# Encode multi-class response variable

Tags: scikit-learn, multiclass-classification, prediction

In a classification problem when the response variable has multi-class, e.g., "sunny","rainy","cloudy", how should we encode it? I know that for predictors like this, usually we do [One Hot Encoding](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), and if a predictors have too many classes, then we might just use the [LabelEncode](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html).

When this multi-class issue occurs in the response variable, I guess we can just use LabelEncode() rather use using One Hot encoding right? Because if we use One Hot encoding, then we will have 2 variables as the response variable, and the machine learning algorithm in sklearn usually expects the response variable not to be a vector right? (I mean it expects a long 1D vector with length equal to the number of observations but not a 2D matrix). But on the other hand, if we just map "sunny", "rainy","cloudy" to {1,2,3} or {0,1,2}, or whatever 3 numbers, that will create a less than or greater than relationship among "sunny", "rainy","cloudy", which is not inherited in the original problem.

Comment: Is this a general classification/prediction question? Please explain what is LabelEncode() and sklearn. If you are talking about some specific library then, either tag or mention.

Comment: _"...and if a predictors have too many classes, then we might just use the LabelEncoder..."_ that is **not** the difference between using OneHot vs Label.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the meaning of the classes, and whether they have any meaningful order.

If they are [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_data) or a scale, then there is a meaningful ordering, and it can potentially be reasonable to order them and then assign labels $1, 2, \dots, n$ in order to the classes.  This is what you call "LabelEncode".  In some cases, some form of regression might also be appropriate and worth trying.

If they are [categorical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable) or [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Nominal_level), with no meaningful ordering, then LabelEncode makes no sense and will be no better than a one-hot encoding -- and potentially worse.  So, the default is one-hot encoding.

If they are categorical but have some hierarchy, there are [smarter methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#Hierarchical_Classification).  You can build a tree that represents the hierarchy, then have a multi-hot encoding.  If there are $n$ classes, you will have a tree with $n$ leaves and (say) $m$ nodes in total  (where $m > n$).  Then you can encode the class as a $m$-vector, whose $i$th entry is 1 if the class is a descendant of node $i$ in the tree, or 0 otherwise.

If the classes are categorical but have various attributes, you can try an encoding that has one element for each possible attribute.  For instance, if there are $k$ binary attributes, you can have a $k$-vector with a 0 or 1 in the $i$th entry according to whether the corresponding class has the $i$th attribute or not.  You can generalize from there for more general situations.

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_data_type) for more about different types of measurements.

Answer (score 1):

This depends largely on the software.  `sklearn` **classifiers** will know not to treat label-encoded data as ordered; that said, most/all of them will take the raw string data just fine (and in many cases will use a `LabelEncoder` internally, for computational efficiency).  If you one-hot encode multiclass data, `sklearn` will generally think your problem is multi*label* instead of just multiclass, and your results will be different.  See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51525043/10495893).

But, in contrast, most neural network implementations will expect multiclass targets to be one-hot encoded in advance, and presumably you'll want to use a softmax activation on the final layer.